# Load Python modules in Elixir

Tags: python-3.x, elixir

I just started with Elixir and I want to run the Python programs from Elixir. I created an Elixir project using **mix**. I've added the required python files in priv/python3 folder and I am able to run the required Python program. But the problem is my Python application requires several libraries, ML models and Pandas Dataframe to be loaded at first. This takes 10-20 seconds. So every time I call the Python function from Elixir all these libraries, models and dataframes will be loaded and it takes much more time to run a simple function. Is there a way to load all the models and dataframes at first in Elixir and use them when Python functions are called instead of loading them every time?

Let me know if any one need more details on this. Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to run python programs in elixir? If you could write your python to stay up long term and communicate via stdin/stdout, you could communicate with it via ports (good intro at https://elixirschool.com/blog/til-ports/) and leave it running

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you need using Erlport (which explicitly supports Python and Ruby).

http://erlport.org/docs/python.html

Not necessary but potentially helpful is also the Elixir wrapper at: https://github.com/fazibear/export

I would probably just call the Erlang version from Elixir.

Erlport should allow you to start the python code once as a Port and then run functions as needed. I think this could be a solution to your problem. (I notice it is old, but not I've typed it all out).